# Wiring both reverse sensors & camera on reverse light - Short circuit threat?

Tags: sensor, camera

I want to install both reverse sensors & screen+camera. My challenge is with the power wiring. Both the screen and the sensors controllers need these wiring:

1. Power from the accumulator
2. Control power from the reverse lights
3. GND

Suppose both controllers will be in the back so I'll need to contact single reverse light cable with the sensors & screen. So it's 3 instead of 1. Same with the accumulator.

Is there are here issues of overloading? Short circuit? etc.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

A better way to handle this is to pull direct power from a fuse (or direct battery power with inline fuse or fusible link) and run it through a relay. Connect a power lead from the reverse lights to power the relay. When the lights come on, the reverse camera will be powered by battery power. The relay draws very little power and should not cause your reverse lights any issues.

Comment: Just to be clear - when you say battery power you mean accumulator?